# Sending SMS using Amazon Web Services's SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

Is it possible to send sms using AWS's SES service. I am trying to implement this functionality using Java.

Answer (score 2):

You can use AWS's SNS to send SMS messages. You could hook up a SES endpoint to SNS to do this via sending an email.

At the moment, only US phone numbers are acceptable for SMS messaging.

See the **Deliver across multiple protocols** heading on http://aws.amazon.com/sns/

Comment: Could you provide a source to the US only restriction?

Comment: Sure - look at http://aws.amazon.com/sns/ under the **Deliver across multiple protocols** heading.

Answer (score 1):

You can now send SMS globally. See [Introducing Worldwide SMS Messaging](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxSP0HUNM8FQ1Y/Introducing-Worldwide-SMS-Messaging)

Answer (score 0):

**Yes u can send bulk SMS using AMazon SNS(Simple notification Service)**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.CreateTopicRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.CreateTopicResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.MessageAttributeValue;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.PublishRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.PublishResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.SubscribeRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.SubscribeResult;

public class BulkSMSSender {
    static String topicArn;
    static Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> smsAttributes;
    static AmazonSNSClient snsClient = AwsSNSCredentials.getSnsClient();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // AmazonSNSClient snsClient = new AmazonSNSClient();

        if (topicArn == null) {
            topicArn = createSNSTopic(snsClient);

        }
        smsAttributes = initializeMessage();
        String message = "*********";
        String phoneNumber[] = { "+91**********" };
        subscribeToTopic(snsClient, topicArn, "sms", phoneNumber[0]);

        sendSMSMessageToTopic(snsClient, topicArn, message, smsAttributes);
    }

    public static String createSNSTopic(AmazonSNSClient snsClient) {
        CreateTopicRequest createTopic = new CreateTopicRequest("Topic");
        CreateTopicResult result = snsClient.createTopic(createTopic);
        System.out.println("Create topic request: " + snsClient.getCachedResponseMetadata(createTopic));
        return result.getTopicArn();
    }

    public static void subscribeToTopic(AmazonSNSClient snsClient, String topicArn, String protocol, String endpoint) {
        SubscribeRequest subscribe = new SubscribeRequest(topicArn, protocol, endpoint);
        SubscribeResult subscribeResult = snsClient.subscribe(subscribe);
        System.out.println("Subscribe request: " + snsClient.getCachedResponseMetadata(subscribe));
    }

    public static void sendSMSMessageToTopic(AmazonSNSClient snsClient, String topicArn, String message,
            Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> smsAttributes) {
        PublishResult result = snsClient.publish(
                new PublishRequest().withTopicArn(topicArn).withMessage(message).withMessageAttributes(smsAttributes));
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> initializeMessage() {
        if (smsAttributes == null) {
            smsAttributes = new HashMap<String, MessageAttributeValue>();
            smsAttributes.put("AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID",
                    new MessageAttributeValue().withStringValue("MSGGGG").withDataType("String"));
            smsAttributes.put("AWS.SNS.SMS.MaxPrice",
                    new MessageAttributeValue().withStringValue("0.05").withDataType("Number"));
            smsAttributes.put("AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType",
                    new MessageAttributeValue().withStringValue("Transactional").withDataType("String"));
        }
        return smsAttributes;

    }

}
```

**The AWS Credentials can be put here**

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient;

import common.PropertiesFileReader;
import constants.StringConstants;

public class AwsSNSCredentials {
    private static final String CLIENT_SMS_TOKEN = "AWS Secret Id";
    private static final String CLIENT_SMS_SECRET = "AWS Secret Key";
    private static final BasicAWSCredentials CREDENTIALS = new BasicAWSCredentials(CLIENT_SMS_TOKEN, CLIENT_SMS_SECRET);

    private static AmazonSNSClient snsClient = null;
    public static AmazonSNSClient getSnsClient() {
        if(null == snsClient) {
        snsClient = new AmazonSNSClient(CREDENTIALS)
                .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2);
        }
        return snsClient;
    }
}
```